# NetBeans 7.1.2 tomcat /manager access configuration issue

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to access the `/manager` page of the Tomcat instance installed by NetBeans 7.1.2.

When I right click the corresponding tree node for properties, I get this:

[image]

which seems to suggest I could use these credentials, but they don't work.

When I take a look at `tomcat-users.xml`, this user does not seem to exist:

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
</tomcat-users>
```

Am I supposed to create it? If yes, I have tried, but could not find the proper roles. What would be the proper line to add? (and yes I have rebooted Tomcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties dialog, you can see two variables:

- **`CATALINA_HOME`**, the directory where you chose to install Tomcat. e. g. `c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0`. Tomcat uses this variable to find its internal classes and libraries.
- **`CATALINA_BASE`** the directory of the configuration files and directories, such as the web application directories. If `CATALINA_BASE` isn't set, it defaults to the value of `CATALINA_HOME`. e. g. `C:\Users\JVerstry\.netBeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base`

If you want to use the manager, you need deploy (copy) the manager application in the proper folder located in `C:\Users\JVerstry\.netBeans\7.1.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base` if this application don't exists (see the directory `conf/Catalina/localhost`) and add the role `manager-gui` to the user

Comment: All that seems to be set-up properly. I finally resorted to installing Tomcat manually and add it in NetBeans.